# post forms inputted value

Tags: php, html, arrays, form-submit

can anyone explain how i get the value that is input into products_price to pass though to the &price=  upon submitting

```
 <form method="post" action="epos_action.php">
```

```
<td width="80%"><?php echo $default_currency_symbol; ?><input type="text" name="products_price" size="14" value="<?php echo(number_format(($_POST['products_price']), 2, '.', '')); ?>">

<td><a width="12%" colspan="1" align="center"><a input type="submit" method="post" value="Submit" class="button" title="<?php echo 'Pay Account'; ?>" href="#"  onclick="this.blur(); window.location.href='epos_action.php?Action=PayBill&ProductID=<?php echo $dummy_product_id; ?>&Quantity=<?php echo $fakeqty;?>&PayName=<?php echo $results['orders_id']; ?>&Price=<?php echo ($_POST['products_price']); ?>'"><span><?php echo 'Make Payment'; ?></span></a></td>
```

(if i put another variable in the &price= it passes the value through to the epos.action.php file as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You must learn about form building, then trying to proccessing data.
[html forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

P.S. You passed  some data via GET method, some via POST. So in php you can access them with

> $_GET \ $_POST

arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the HTTP verb you're using, you can use [$ _GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) or [$ _POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). On the form, you're using POST, and if you pass variables via URL you are using GET

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @mcklayin, you need to first understand how forms works and your code clearly shows that you don't.

First, you can't use  as an input element. Use `<input type="submit">`
Second, you can only use the method attribute with forms, not elements.
And lastly, you need to be clear about what you want to achieve using that (mutant button+link) element. If you want to direct the user to another page upon clicking, then no need to us js. Just an ordinary link